# a question on using xhtml2pdf to parse css from website

Tags: python

I am trying to use xhtml2pdf to convert a webpage to pdf. After reading out the content of the webpage using urllib2, I found pisa.CreatePDF needs to process every link in the webpage content too. Especially, whenever it tried to parse .css file after I tried several websites, I got the following error:

```
pisa-3.0.33-py2.6.egg/sx/w3c/cssParser.py", line 1020, in _parseExpressionTerm
sx.w3c.cssParser.CSSParseError: Terminal function expression expected closing ')':: (u'Alpha(Opacity', u'=0); }\n\n\n\n.ui-state-')
```

Do you seem this issue too? Could anyone please help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well it strikes me that this is (what is being perceived as) a problem in the css itself, and that the error is simply reporting a missing ')' in the source. Any more info on this?

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? If yes, what was the fix? I am running into the similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

> pisa-3.0.33-py2.6.egg/sx/w3c/cssParser.py", line 1020, in
>   _parseExpressionTerm sx.w3c.cssParser.CSSParseError: Terminal function expression expected closing ')':: (u'Alpha(Opacity', u'=0);
>   }\n\n\n\n.ui-state-')

I think it was because it didn't recognize your css, which is alpha(opacity bla.. bla

I was having that problem before because of my javascript, I removed them and now it works.

Comment: This is not very pratic if the OP does not control the page he is trying to convert